# Unable to automatically number figures in word doc

Tags: ms-word

I am not able to no. the figures automatically in MS word.

Its showing me a code like- `Figure { SEQ Figure \* ARABIC }:`

Please help me in how can I change this to no. format.

Thanks

Comment: This is an end-user question and is therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please ask such questions in an appropriate venue, such as Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Word's field code display toggled 'on'. Pressing Alt-F9 toggles it on/off.